# Use existing SSH key pair with openSSH to connect to a server

Tags: ubuntu

My colleague has provided me with an SSH key pair files (public key and private key files) to be used to connect to a remote Linux server, that has the public key in its `authorized_keys` File.

I'm currently using windows 10, and I have openSSH client already installed on my machine.

I'm not sure how SSH works exactly, but I want to know how to make my openSSH client knows about the public and private keys I have, and make it use them to connect to the remote server.

**Note**: my openSSH client is currently working with an existing key pair `id_rsa` to connect with my Gitlab account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to use this is to use the "`-i`" option to use the private key you were given, eg

```
ssh -i /path/to/private.key user@ssh.server.name
```

From a security pov I would be concerned your friend has provided you a private key - that is not a best practice. The correct way is for you to use your public key (id_rsa.pub) and then give him a copy of it  to add to the servers authorized_keys file  while keeping the private key private.  You should not trust the private key he has given you for anything other then connecting to the server he has asked you to connect to (and even then, if appropriate, you should update the authorized_keys file to use the public key you generated - and a new one for him if applicable)

Further Details:

You typically put your keys in (home_directory)/.ssh - Per the manual

```
 -i identity_file
         Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk,
         ~/.ssh/id_ed25519, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.  Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple
         -i options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).  If no certificates have been explicitly specified by the CertificateFile directive, ssh will also try to
         load certificate information from the filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to identity filenames.
```

If you want to automatically use a given key pair specific to a host you can use the CertificateFile directive (I've never played with this) or more commonly create / add appropriate lines to your ~/.ssh/config file to use a specific key for a host - I believe it would look something like this:

```
  Host host-nick-name
        Hostname ip.addr.of.host
        User myusername
        IdentityFile /path/to/identity.file
```

Comment: An SSH client does need the public key, as it has to "offer" keys to the server before one is tentatively accepted. Sure, `ssh` can extract the public key out of the private file, but if someone had multiple keypairs configured, that would mean entering the decryption passphrases for *all* of them – whereas if it finds the accompanying `.pub` files it can offer those directly, and only ask for the passphrase of the *one* key that was actually accepted.

Comment: @user1686 Interesting point - I'm not sure how just much  this matters that much in practice. I just renamed my id_rsa.pub file ,then tried to ssh into a server I run (with ssh -v host.name  after killing ssh_agent.) and it authenticated fine using  public auth   The debug log also included the following line : **debug1: Trying private key: /home/davidgo/.ssh/id_rsa**   -  I guess if you don't specify multiple private keys and use id_rsa it will work - although ssh_agent didn't work for me until it could find the public key.

Answer (score 0):

Normally on Windows with OpenSSH the private key file would need to live at `C:\Users\[your username]\.ssh\id_rsa` (or id_ed25519 or id_ecdsa or whatever).

That said, if you're wanting to connect to an SSH server on Windows I'd recommend PuTTY. Convert the key to a ppk using puttygen and then open putty.exe.

- specify the keys path in Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> Private key file for authentication.
- specify your username in Connection -> Data -> Auto-login username
- specify your hostname in Session -> Host Name (or IP address)
- name the session in Session -> Saved Sessions and click the Save button
- once all that's done click on Open